# What do the numbers following the linear-gradient() do?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm looking through this [SNES controller][1] made with HTML and CSS. The background here is taken almost directly from this. I was wondering what the [num] [num] / [num] [num] no-repeat following the linear-gradient() does. I can't seem to find any documentation on numbers following gradients outside their parentheses.

```css
body {
  height: 100% width: 100% margin: 0px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 17vmin 17vmin, grey 16.95vmin, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 17vmin), radial-gradient(circle at 63vmin 17vmin, grey 16.95vmin, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 17vmin), linear-gradient(grey 0 0) 50% 0/46vmin 30vmin no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

It doesn't work here for some reason though. Any thoughts?
[1]: https://codepen.io/alvaromontoro/pen/PoEgRPG

Comment: Documentation on background is abundant e.g. here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background Gradients are images in this context.